# R plotting max values for weekdays

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I have this data frame. It is an hourly data and I found max value for each day. I am trying to get every daily maximum values for the week of the day for each Site_Name. So for example maximum values of every Monday,Tueaday etc. within the data for each Site Name.

```
Site_Name              Date            x1     x2   x3
Aldergrove       2022-01-01 00:00      10     12   14
Aldergtove       2022-01-02 01:00       8     11    5
Aldergtove       2022-01-03 02:00       5      9    8
Aldergtove       2022-01-04 03:00      15     10   13
Aldergtove       2022-01-05 04:00      10     10   10
Aldergtove       2022-01-06 05:00       9      5    9
Heathrow         2022-01-01 00:00      14     19    5
Heathrow         2022-01-02 01:00      12     17   11
Heathrow         2022-01-03 02:00       7     12    0
...
```

I have tried doing this. Although it is plotting 1 maximum value for each day of the week per site.

```
wday_summary <- df %>% 
  group_by(Site_Name, wday(date, label = TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(across(x1:x3,  list(mean = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                                min = ~ min(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                max = ~ max(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
  rename(Week_Day = 'wday(Date, label = TRUE)')


wday_summary %>%
  filter(Site_Name %in% c("Aldergrove","Heathrow","Leuchars","Shawbury")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Week_Day, x1_max, col = Site_Name)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Although I need my plot to show the maximum value of all days falling into the weekday category looking like this;
[image]

Comment: *"daily maximum values for the week"* ... does this mean week-of-year, so that you'd summarize over (up to) 52 weeks? (It's not really clear what is desired/needed or wrong here.)

Comment: fyi you can use `group_by(Site_Name, Week_Day = wday(date, label = TRUE)) %>%` to avoid the later renaming step.

Comment: Your question is still confusing me. If there are 52 Mondays per site (are there?), what is the difference between "all Monday's max values" and "all Monday's values"?

Comment: Perhaps there are multiple observations per day per site? If so, you just need to add `date` to your `group_by` to get the maximum value per site per day.

Comment: Is the issue that you want to plot the max `x1` and the max `x2` and the max `x3`, but your plot is only showing the max `x1`? Or that you want to show, row-wise, the max of (x1, x2, x3)?